# Could not display data from php mysql in listview java

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, listview

Please help im new in java...
im not able to display data in listview

**PHP side**

```
    <?
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("my server","username here"," my password");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("db");

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE 1  ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

I have 3 layout

**main layout**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3E70D" >

   <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="10dip" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvordername"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>        

</ScrollView>
```

**Second layout**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ColImgPath"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColImgID"
            android:text="Column 1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColImgDesc"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Third layout is use to display more detail and single record**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/fullimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/custom_full_order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java side my complete code**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.android.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.android.library.UserFunctions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OrderActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order);


        //listview
        final ListView lstview1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String url = "my server address http:";

        try{
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String>map;

            for(int i= 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("ImageID", c.getString("ImageID"));
                map.put("ImageDesc", c.getString("ImageDesc"));
                map.put("ImagePath", c.getString("ImagePath"));
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }

            lstview1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

            final AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            lstview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullorder_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fullimage));
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
                try
                {
                    image.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(MyArrList.get(position).get("Imagepath")));
                } catch (Exception e){
                    //if get error
                    image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
                }
                imageDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                imageDialog.setTitle("View : " + MyArrList.get(position).get("comment"));
                imageDialog.setView(layout);
                imageDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                    imageDialog.create();
                    imageDialog.show();
                }

            });
        } catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

            context = c;
            MyArr = list;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return MyArr.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
            }
            //colimage
            ImageView imageView =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height= 100;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width= 100;
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            try
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(MyArr.get(position).get("ImagePath")));

            } catch (Exception e){
                //if get error
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
            }

            //colposition
            TextView txtPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgID);
            txtPosition.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            txtPosition.setText("ID : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageID"));

            //colpicname
            TextView txtPicName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgDesc);
            txtPicName.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
            txtPicName.setText("DEesc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageDesc"));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
    //get json code from url
    public String getJSONUrl(String url){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file...");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    //get image resource from url
    private static final String TAG = "ERROR";
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            copy(in,out);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSamplesize=1;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
            closeStream(out);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static void closeStream(Closeable stream){
        if(stream != null) {
            try{
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1){
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**my logcat**

```
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298): org.json.JSONException: Value <? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298):    at com.example.androidjhfong.OrderActivity.onCreate(OrderActivity.java:77)
01-26 21:58:35.594: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
01-26 21:58:35.599: W/System.err(14298):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 21:58:35.719: I/Timeline(14298): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@423fd758 time:785573323
```

Comment: what error do you get? or what exactly shows up wrong?

Comment: it did not run anything

Comment: The first line of your logcat tells it all.

Comment: About your main layout: do not put a ListView in a ScrollView.

Comment: where can i refer the example in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You have real mess in your code. Firstly you shouldn't connect to web in main thread (it blocks app, cause "application not responding"). For fetching JSON I would recommend [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Understand-the-basics-of-RoboSpice-in-30-seconds).

Secondly in `ImageAdapter.getItem` you should return `MyArr.get(position)` not `position`.

Answer (score 0):

I think greenapps and MAGx2 have the right hints for the solution.

I'd like to add that it might be better to use a few open source libraries for the other things.

- picasso for image downloading + displaying
- gson for json parsing
- okhttp for normal downloads

Also, don't use things like this:

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height= 100;
```

It really messes up when you view on other devices with different DPI